# How to create a dictionary, where the key is the key of a dictionary of lists and the value is the longest list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this dictionary of lists of dictionaries:

```
dict_countries ={'uk': [{'datetime': '1955-10-10 17:00:00', 'city': 'chester'},{'datetime': '1956-09-10 13:00:00', 'city': 'london'}],'us': [{'datetime': '1974-10-10 23:00:00', 'city': 'hudson'}]}
```

So far I have wrote this function (I cannot use tuples). The funciton must return a dictionary where the Key is the name of the country with the most sights (dicctionaries inside its list) and the values is the number os sights :

```
def country_with_most_sights(dict_countries:dict)-> dict:

 record_dict = {}

for country in dict_countries 
 N_sights = len(each_country)
  if N_sights > record_dict[past_country]:
   past_country = ***country´s name*** 
      record_dict[past_country] = N_sights

return record_dict
```

The desired result will be record_dict to be:

```
record_dict = {uk:2}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways you can do this. Here are a few:

1. Find the lengths of each value, then find item that has the longest length using `max` and the `key` argument.

   ```
   def country_with_most_sights(dict_countries:dict)-> dict:
       return dict([max(((k, len(v)) for k, v in dict_countries.items()), key=lambda x: x[1])])
   ```

   Explanation:

   - Find the `max()` of the `items()` in your dictionary.
   - Each element of `dict.items()` is a tuple containing the key and value.
   - We convert this to a tuple containing the key and the length of the value using the generator expression `((k, len(v)) for k, v in dict_countries.items())`
   - By specifying that lambda function, we use the the second element of this tuple (i.e. the length of the value) as the criterion to find the max.
2. Use only the `.keys()` of the dict and index into the original dict using this key in your lambda.

   ```
   def country_with_most_sights(dict_countries:dict)-> dict:
       max_key = max(dict_countries.keys(), key=lambda k: len(dict_countries[k]))
       max_val = len(dict_countries[k])
       return {max_key: max_val}
   ```
3. Iterate over the keys of your dict and keep track of the longest value. Then return that key and its length:

   ```
   def country_with_most_sights(dict_countries:dict)-> dict:
       longest_country = "none"
       num_sights = 0
       for k, v in dict_countries.items():
           if len(v) > num_sights:
               longest_country = k
               num_sights = len(v)
       return {longest_country: num_sights}
   ```

   Explanation:

   - Iterate over `dict.items()`
   - if the length of the value is more than anything you've seen before, save the key and value in the `longest_country` and `num_sights` variables.
   - After you're done with all items in the dict, create the return value from your variables and return it.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_countries = {'uk': [{'datetime': '1955-10-10 17:00:00', 'city': 'chester'},
                         {'datetime': '1956-09-10 13:00:00', 'city': 'london'}],
                  'us': [{'datetime': '1974-10-10 23:00:00', 'city': 'hudson'}]}

val = 0
k = ''
for key in dict_countries.keys():
    qqq = len(dict_countries[key])
    if qqq > val:
        val = qqq
        k = key

ttt = {k: val}
```

Output

```
{'uk': 2}
```

Updating the maximum size of the lists, via the variable 'val'.